# Obtener un elemento HTML con jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf

En estos momentos me encuentro con un problema al usar la libreria jspdf y busco sacar un reporte de una tabla de datos, aunque me saca el pdf no agarra para nada el elemento html que necesito en el reporte

**Función JavaScript**

```
$("#generarPDF").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let doc = new jsPDF();
        const tabla = document.getElementById("tabla");
        doc.setFontSize(20);
        doc.text("Reportes", 20, 20);
        doc.html(tabla, {
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            callback: function (doc) {
                doc.save("reporte.pdf")
            },

        });
        doc.save("reporte.pdf");
    });
```

**HTML que requiero en el pdf**

```
<table class="table text-center" id="tabla">
                <thead class="table-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
                        <th scope="col">SI</th>
                        <th scope="col">V</th>
                        <th scope="col">DV</th>
                        <th scope="col">SC</th>
                        <th scope="col">Observación</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                        <?php
                            if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 2){
                                echo '<th scope="col">Usuario</th>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        <th scope="col">Municipio</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ ?>
                        <tr id="<?php echo $fila['idventas']; ?>">
                            <td><input type='checkbox' class="delete_checkbox" name='ids[]' value="<?php echo $fila['idventas']?>"></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['nombreCliente'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['saldoInicial'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['venta'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['devueltoVacio'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['saldoCliente'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['observacion'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $fila['fechaVenta'];?></td>
                            <?php
                                if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 2){
                                    echo "<td>".$fila['username']."</td>";
                                }
                                ?>    
                            <td><?php echo $fila['nombreMunicipio']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Siento que igual y es el metodo html() ya que me guarda el texto y el pdf pero no la tabla, Por cierto estoy usando JavaScript vanilla y este es el CDN con la versión

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
```

También me imprime este error en consola lo cual me deja pensando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: ya lo actualice gracias por la corrección

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con el plugin **jspdf-autotable**?

https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>

<table class="table text-center" id="tabla">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Cliente</th>
      <th scope="col">SI</th>
      <th scope="col">V</th>
      <th scope="col">DV</th>
      <th scope="col">SC</th>
      <th scope="col">Observación</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Municipio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Edward</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Sin observaciones</td>
      <td>01/06/2022</td>
      <td>Municipio</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><br>

<button id="buttonPDF">Generar PDF</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#buttonPDF').click(function() {
  var doc = new jsPDF()
  doc.autoTable({ html: '#tabla' })
  doc.save('table.pdf')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/romeroedward18/xgc4muvs/19/